# Expressjs Morgan dynamically format the logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, express

Attempting to change the format of morgan's logging through the application run time.

The value will change pending on some remote value in a database and I would like morgan's output to change as a result. 
ie. If in the database the value is 1 morgan's formatting is 'dev', if the value is 3 the formatting is 'combined'

I have the been using the following line to set up morgan with formatting:

```
app.use(morgan(get_verbose()))
   .use ....
```

where get_verbose will correspond to the format options.
However it is not giving the dynamic results I was wishing for - it's only setting the formatting once.

Am I going about this incorrectly or is morgan limited to only 1 format at run time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to create a middleware function that "wraps" the Morgan middleware:

```
var morganDev = mordan('dev');
var morganCombined = morgan('combined');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var value = /* get value somehow */

    if (value === 1) {
        morganDev(req, res, next);
    } else if (value === 3) {
        morganCombined(req, res, next);
    }
});
```

Up front, you create one logger for each log format you would like, but don't attach either of them to the app. In their place, a custom function reads the value and chooses which logger should handle the processing for this request.

**Safety update:** There should be a catch-all `else` block to handle the case where `value` is neither 1 or 3. This block should call `next()` directly, otherwise the request handling will stall and never return a response to the client.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to accomplish this with Morgan's built-in features is the `skip` parameter. From the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#skip):

```
// EXAMPLE: only log error responses
morgan('combined', {
  skip: function (req, res) { return res.statusCode < 400 }
})
```

The `skip` option specifies a function with parameters `req` and `res` that returns `True/False` to determine if the logging option should be skipped. The function can contain any necessary code as long as it returns `True` or `False`.

Depending on what parameter you want to differentiate logging on, this may be a simpler way then a multi-line if/else block. An example server logging HTTPS traffic separately from HTTP traffic:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const logger = require('morgan');

const httpsOptions = // {} hash of options.

app.use(logger('combined', {
  stream: httpLogStream,
  skip: function(req, res) { return req.secure }
});
app.use(logger('combined', {
  stream: httpsLogStream,
  skip: function(req, res) { return !req.secure }
});

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(443);
```

A good walk through for setting up HTTPS as I did in this example can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openssl-essentials-working-with-ssl-certificates-private-keys-and-csrs).

To read about Express's `req.secure` method: [here](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.secure).

The log streams are set up as in [Morgan's documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#write-logs-to-a-file).